# How can I "hg copy" a directory in a Mercurial project in Sourcetree 2.0 for the Mac?

Tags: svn, mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree

I want to mirror a directory across different parts of a repository but when I select a directory and then choose the Copy... command nothing happens. FYI When I select a file and do this it does work, but I want this behaviour to work with a directory (just like SVN: externals). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with [subrepos](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository).

You might also find [this](http://www.swiftsoftwaregroup.com/hg-subrepositories-a-how-to-guide-for-the-svnexternals-junkie-part-1/) informative.

The copy command isn't meant to work that way. When you hg copy a file, you are telling mercurial that if you later have to merge changes from another branch that affect the original file, the changes coming from that other branch must also be applied to the copy. 
To put it another way, if a change to the original file is in a descendant commit of the copy commit, the change will not be propagated to the copy file.

Comment: Thanks @Kindread for clearing that up and for the article comparing SVN Externals with Mercurial Subrepos. Subrepos it is then.....